# how to have a page extension with ?page= behind

Tags: php, wordpress

how to have a php page with the link below.

```
www.example.com/example/?page=user
```

I wanna create a page with the URL above. I'm using Wordpress as my CMS, all the pages that I create will be like www.example.com/example/, without the extension.

I wanna have lot's of page under www.example.com/example/ like

```
www.example.com/example/?page=user
 www.example.com/example/?page=admin
 www.example.com/example/?page=search
```

Comment: you want to create such URLs or you already have them and need to know how to process?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $page = '';
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) $page = stripslashes($_GET['page']);
    if(!empty($page)) include($page.'.php');
?>
```

I'm giving you this code assuming you have some knowledge in PHP to use it correctly

Comment: I would reccomend to just use $_GET, and not $_REQUEST since it's superglobal and covers _GET, _POST, and _COOKIE.

Comment: Having to if "troughout" the whole script seems redundant to me. The url's also look ugly. Imo he should write a routing or use the routing available in wordpress.